Why I am getting odd results from calibrateRobotWorldHandEye()?
I am working on calibration of camera-robot system using a 8*5 chessboard fixed on the table and a UR5 robot.
The main function here is cv2.calibrateRobotWorldHandEye() I have R_base2gripper and t_base2gripper resulted by forward kinematics computing R_gripper2base and t_gripper2base so they are inverted and utilized as inputs of the calibration function. Also, R_target2cam and t_target2cam are extracted directly from cv2.solvePnP using intrinsics which are accurate enough as well as image point and their corresponding object points.
The issue is related to unexpected results due to unknown mistakes.
More clearly, t_base2target must have roughly zero in z-axis and t_gripper2cam less than 20 cm (0.2) in all axis although none of them has been satisfied and there are large deviation form the expectations. Results in translation part is around 4 to 8 m, crazily.
Here are two functions I used to compute the transformations required by cv2.calibrateRobotWorldHandEye() as input. Much appreciation for your helpful comments.
Note: In my terminology, world is replaced by target.
def compute_base2gripper(calib: RobotExtrinsicCalibration):
    R_base2gripper, t_base2gripper = [], []
    nConf = len(calib.configurations)
    end_effector = calib.robot.numLinks() - 1
    for iConf in range(nConf):
        calib.robot.setConfig(calib.configurations[iConf])
        R, t = calib.robot.link(end_effector).getTransform()
        R, t = np.array(R).reshape(3, 3), np.array(t)

        R_base2gripper.append(R.T)
        t_base2gripper.append(-R.T @ t)
    
    R_base2gripper = np.array(R_base2gripper)
    t_base2gripper = np.array(t_base2gripper)

    return R_base2gripper, t_base2gripper[:, :, np.newaxis]


def compute_target2cam(calib: RobotExtrinsicCalibration):
    mtx = np.array(calib.cameras['camera0'].intrinsics['matrix'])
    dist = np.array(calib.cameras['camera0'].intrinsics['distortion'])
    objpts = np.array(calib.markers[0].local_features)
    nFeature = objpts.shape[0]
    nFrame = int(len(calib.observations) / nFeature)
    obs = np.array(calib.observations).reshape(nFrame, -1)

    R_target2cam, t_target2cam = [], []
    for iFrame in range(nFrame):
        frames_id.append(obs[iFrame, 0].frame_id)
        imgpts = []
        for iFeature in range(nFeature):
            imgpts.append(obs[iFrame, iFeature].value)
        imgpts = np.array(imgpts)

        ret, R, t = cv2.solvePnP(objpts, imgpts, mtx, dist)

        if ret:
            R, _ = cv2.Rodrigues(R)
        else:
            raise ValueError('Not able to compute target pose relative to the camera')

        R_target2cam.append(R)
        t_target2cam.append(t)

    R_target2cam = np.array(R_target2cam)
    t_target2cam = np.array(t_target2cam)

    return R_target2cam, t_target2cam

